# How to see the features used in random forest?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, feature-extraction, feature-detection

Currently, I'm working on Random Forest for classification. and I have problems showing the used features in my model.

here's some of my code

```
model=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=estimator, max_depth=depth, max_features=feature)# a simple random forest model
model.fit(train_X,train_y)# now fit our model for training data
prediction=model.predict(test_X)
```

I'm using hyper-parameter for the model parameter, especially for the max_features. the input can be 3, 5, and none (use all features).

here are my features:

A1_feat
A2_feat
A3_feat
A4_feat
A5_feat
A6_feat
A7_feat
A8_feat
B_feat
C_feat

and status for the class or label

**for example, I'm using 5 features. then I want to know which features are being used??**

The output it should be A1_feat, A3_feat, A5_feat, B_feat, and C_feat

Answer (score 1):

You could use `feature_importances_` attribute of your classifier.

For instance:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

feature_importances = DataFrame(model.feature_importances_,
                                index = train_X.columns,
                                columns=['importance'])
                                .sort_values('importance', 
                                             ascending=False)

print(feature_importances)
```

In my case, the output is:

```
Feature Importance

       importance
sc       0.158446
al       0.143696
pcv      0.142879
rbcc     0.137623
sg       0.085623
.
.
```

Also, you can plot:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from matplotlib.pyplot import title


figure(figsize=(12,3))
features = test_X.columns.values.tolist()
importance = model.feature_importances_.tolist()
feature_series = Series(data=importance, index=features)
feature_series.plot.bar()
title('Feature Importance')
```

In my case, the graph is:
[image]

Comment: I think thats not what i want.. But thanks for the answer, maybe i will need that later

Comment: Hmmm, Maybe I misunderstood your question. You want to know which features are being used by random forest? If I'm right, then you can use your classifiers 'feature_importances_' attribute. Why?  If the listed feature is 0, then your feature is not used at all. If it is non-zero, then you know that the feature has an impact on classification

Comment: still can't.. the models have been built by all features, so the listed features will be non-zero.. because all of my features are important, or at least have an impact to the models.. what I want is use some of the features, then I can see which features have been selected.. thanks for your answer btw

Comment: Hmm, I understand, but the question you asked was ***Which features have an impact on my classifier?*** Now you are asking ***How can I use some of the features?*** They are two different questions. You want to select features based on the highest impact. I would suggest this [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html), and if you have still problem then you should create a new question with a `feature-selection` tag.